# Way to group labels on chart.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js2

Is there any way to group labels from legend on chart.js. Observe the current situation that I have: 
[image]

I want to group humidity labels, inside temperature and outside temperature. Where I will be able to show/hide them on single click. For instance if I click on single humidity label, both inside and outside humidity would show. I'm also familiar with the function `generateLegend()` but documentation didn't helped me to find right solution.